# How can I save/export pdf from word with same png resolution?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I am using Word 2013. I inserted PNG and TIF images in the Word file. I exported the word file to PDF, but I saw their images are very low resolution.

I tried to increase the compression quality for pictures:

- Advanced > Image Size and Quality
- File 
  → Save As 
  → Save as Type: PDF
- Tools 
  → Compress Pictures 
  → (x) Print (220 PPI)...

but the image in the PDF still is low resolution.

How can I save/export the PDF file with same resolution in my Word file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different PDF tool, the built in PDF feature in Word is really nice and usually sufficient, but trying to maintain image quality might be an issue.

You can get a freetrial of NitroPDF (my favorite):
https://www.gonitro.com/

Or, PFDcreator is free:
http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator

These tools will allows you more options when creating/publishing a PDFs.

Comment: This is really good tool

Comment: But nitropdf broken my equation

Answer (score 0):

In Word under `File > Export` you should see two different options for creating a PDF: `Create Adobe PDF` and `Create PDF/XPF Document`. Use the latter whenever image quality matters. `Save As. . . > PDF (*.pdf)` takes you to the same place.

To further improve image quality:

1. Go into the `More options. . .` menu before saving

[image: A screenshot of Word's Save As PDF menu with the More Options button highlighted in a red box]

2. Confirm your optimization level is `Standard (publishing online and printing)` and click `Options. . .`

[image: A screenshot of Word's second Save as PDF menu showing the optimization level radio select menu and the Options button.]

3. De-select `PDF/A Compliant` and select `Optimize for image quality`. Save these settings and they will carry over to future PDF/XPF Document exports

[image: A screenshot of Word's PDF Options menu.]

These settings do not result in a *perfect* PDF, but their fidelity to the original Word document is a fair sight better than the other export option and the file size trade-off is usually reasonable.